# Reorderan array using an user defined order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i want to reorder, in php, an array using a particular defined list.

For example i have this array:

```
['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'black', 'orange', 'white']
```

The order of this **input array** may be different in some occasion, but in every case I need a function that shuffles the array entries (of course only if present, the input array may have only two entries) following this predetermined order:

```
['white', 'black', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow, 'green']
```

I, frankly, do not know how to do unless you use the "search for that item and if there is put in the first position" .. but I think it's a crap code :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a built-in way to do this, but you could use `usort` to sort it according to your preferred order:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    $order = ['white', 'black', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green'];
    $k1 = array_search($a, $order);
    $k2 = array_search($b, $order);
    return $k1 < $k2 ? -1 : +1;
});
```

Comment: It will work with any number of items. usort will process one item after the other, no matter how many there is.

Comment: but does this condition change? return $k1 < $k2 ? -1 : +1;

Comment: Have a look at the documentation for usort: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php "-1" means element "a" should go before element "b", "+1" means element "a" should go after element "b".